# How to use or use not a tag basing on a condition in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, tags, conditional-statements

How could I correctly use the following?

```
{ bool submitter = value; }

...

@(submitter ? "" : @"<a href=""" + Url.Action(actionName, "Queue") + @""">")
<div>
    ...
</div>
@(submitter ? "" : "</a>")
```

My error is that the anchor tag definition is being outputed like it should be in a HTML code right to the web browser and instead of seeing a link around the `<div>` I see the `<a href="...` etc.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want that encoded, then you need to use the Raw extension method:

```
@Html.Raw(submitter ? "" : @"<a href=""" + Url.Action(actionName, "Queue") + @""">")
<div>
    ...
</div>
@Html.Raw(submitter ? "" : "</a>")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you cannot put block level elements, like `div`, inside inline elements like `a`, unless you use HTML5. I guess from your description you aren't.

If you're checking in a browser DOM inspector, you will see your code looks something like this:

```html
<div></div>
<a href="queue/action"></a>
<div></div>
<a></a>
```

The alternative is to change your `div` to `span` and set `display: block` on it in CSS if you require.

Also, that kind of logic would be better placed in a ViewModel.

Comment: I **am** using the HTML5 and hence my direct code like `<a><div></div></a>` works perfectly. All I need is to conditionally create a tag or not create.

Comment: In which case your code should work. What happens when you exlplicitly set `{ bool submitter = true; }`?

Comment: the code (`<a href=` etc) comes to the client HTML-encoded, which I dont want to. So The link does not happen to be a link, just a text.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that I've: found

```
@(new MvcHtmlString(@"<a href=""..."">blah blah</a>"))
```